# Dynamic variable code not working

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-7.1

I have written following lines of code in php like below

```
$keyarguments = array($orlastname,$oradmissionno,$orcourse,$orgender,$ordob,$orrollno,$ormiddlename,$oremail,$orguardian,$orphone,$orfullname,$orfirstmiddle,$orfirstlast);

    foreach ($keyarguments as $key) { 
        ${$key} = array('$or' => array(array("dummy_feild" => new MongoRegex("/$empty/i"))));
    }
```

I want that code should be executed like

```
orlastname = array('$or' => array(array("dummy_feild" => new MongoRegex("/$empty/i"))));
oradmissionno = array('$or' => array(array("dummy_feild" => new MongoRegex("/$empty/i"))));
...
...
...
```

and so on

Please help!!!

Comment: yeah, where is your problem?

Comment: It throws error messages  Undefined variable: orlastname, ...

Comment: And where is `$orlastname` coming from? Ever considered just sticking to arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, use string as the $keyarguments's elemnt.

```
$keyarguments = array('orlastname', 'oradmissionno');
```

Comment: I am not getting you

Comment: I just put it an example, you need to replase all your variable with string. That to say, use `'orlastname'` instead of `$orlastname`.